# Call a script from a git hook

Tags: bash, git, githooks

Let's say I have two scripts in server /hooks folder:

First one initiates logging and writes essential information about push: (post-receive)

```
#!/bin/sh
read oldrev newrev refname
LOGFILE=post-receive.log
echo " push - Old SHA: $oldrev -> $newrev >> $LOGFILE
sh ./post-receive-logic >> $LOGFILE
```

Second one does actual deploying: (post-receive-logic)

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/proj
pm2 stop ~/proj/main.js
git --git-dir ~/proj/.git --work-tree ~/proj pull
npm install
pm2 restart ~/proj/main.js
echo "finished"
```

When I push a commit, second script never gets called: no changes in working tree, no server being killed and restarted, no output specific to second script.

If I call `./post-receive-logic` by hand, everything goes fine, server stops, files being pulled, server starts again.

I tried call it without `sh`, like this:

```
./post-receive-logic >> $LOGFILE
```

but no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are the permissions the same on the two scripts?

Comment: Did you try using the full path to the script as well?

Comment: @HBHB OH I didn't think about that, the sctipts are called from repository  root, I should have written  `./hooks/post-receive-logic >> $LOGFILE`.

Comment: exactly. You could use the full path as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exercise: where is `.` (or `$PWD`) during the post-receive hook operation?

When *you* run it, it's whatever *your* `$PWD` is.  What about when it's run automatically?  (Have a look in the receiving system's bare git repository: your `$LOGFILE` output will be in that directory.)

(There's a missing close quote in the hook text in your posting, so presumably you hand-copied some part(s) of the script and perhaps there's something else missing.  Also, be sure the hook has execute-permission.  But my guess is that you're being bitten by the fact that git runs hooks with `$PWD` set to the `.git` directory, not the hook directory.)

(Side note: your hook is probably incomplete, as it only reads one `oldrev newrev refname`, but a `git push` can push many refs.  Normally you should loop: `while read oldrev newrev refname; do ...; done`.  If you have a pre-receive hook that rejects pushes that push more than one ref, though, this particular post-receive hook could be correct.)

Comment: Totally forgot about $PWD being repository root, thanks! As for missing quote, it's because I'm bad at copy-pasting.