# How to run a script on every commit in a github repo?

Tags: bash, shell, nginx

I want to run a shell script to notify a running nginx server every time there is a commit on a Github repo and copy the changes in a specific folder. Any simple ways to do this?

Comment: WebHooks is your answer :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call a script from a git hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526961/call-a-script-from-a-git-hook)

Comment: @MatiasBarrios Yes and No. Since the post did not solved and needs to play with it to see whether it works for me or not.

Comment: @Hackerman well, do you have suggestions for the webhook nginx script?

Comment: https://developer.github.com/webhooks/

Comment: @Hackerman I looked into these topics before post a question, my problem a bit more complex, when I have hugo docker that needs to be automuaticlly build based on the github content. Dose webhook do this job?